# Write down the matrix of this transformation with respect to the given ?basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let T : M2(R) → M2(R) be the linear transformation defined by
T(A) = 2A + 3A^T. Write down the matrix of this transformation with respect to the basis
{Ei, 1 ≤ i ≤ 4} where

```
                       E1 =    |1 0| , 
                               |0 0|

                      E2= |0 1|
                          |0 0|   

               E3 = |0 0| and
                    |1 0|  
                          E4 =| 0 0|           
                              | 0 1|
```

My attempt ;

T(|1 0|) = 2 |1 0|  + 3 |1 0|  = | 5 0|

```
|0 0|     |0 0|   |0 0|  | 0 0| 


          T (| 0 1| ) = 2 | 0 1| + 3  | 0 1| = | 0 5|  
             | 0 0|       | 0 0|      | 0 0|   | 0 0|
```

I Don't know whethear  im in the  rigt way or in wrong way....PLiz  help me,

Comment: $T(A)$ is only defined when $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix. Therefore $T(1\ 0)$ does not really make sense. On the other hand $$T\left(\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}\right)$$ et cetera will be relevant.

Comment: Your $T$ matrix is $4\times4$.

Comment: im not getting @ jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Your calculations, at its present form, is hard to understand. You will get more respones if the question is easy to read and understand.

Comment: i don't know how to use maths jax,i was trying last time also  i write the symbol for example \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx.....but it doesnot  convert into mathematical form ,@ krish..

Comment: You need to calculate $T(E_1), T(E_2), T(E_3)$ and $T(E_4)$. Because $E_2^T=E_3$, you see that $T(E_2)=2E_2+3E_3$. Ok? Then do the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is to let $T : M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R) \rightarrow M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R)$ be the linear transformation $T(A) = 2A + 3A^t,$ and that we want to find the matrix of $T.$

Because the domain and co-domain each have four dimensions, the matrix of $T$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix. The $i$th column of the matrix of $T$ is the coordinate matrix of $T(E_i)$ denoted by $[T(E_i)].$  We compute
$$\begin{align}
[T(E_1)] & = \left[ \begin{bmatrix}5 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \right] = [5E_1 + 0E_2 + 0E_3 + 0E_4] = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\\\\
[T(E_2)] & = \left[ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2\\ 3 & 0\end{bmatrix} \right] = [0E_1 + 2E_2 + 3E_3 + 0E_4] = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 2\\ 3\\ 0\end{bmatrix},\\\\
[T(E_3)] & = \left[ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 3\\ 2 & 0\end{bmatrix} \right] = [0E_1 + 3E_2 + 2E_3 + 0E_4] = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 3\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \mbox{ and}\\\\
[T(E_4)] & = \left[ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 5\end{bmatrix} \right] = [0E_1 + 0E_2 + 0E_3 + 5E_4] = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 5\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
Thus, the matrix of $T$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 5\end{bmatrix}.$$